# Graph Help - Discrete Math

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

[image]

The vertices indicate where cashiers are located; the edges denote unblocked aisles between cashiers. The department store wants to set up a security system where (plainclothes) guards are placed at certain cashier locations so that each cashier either has a guard at his or her location or is only one aisle away from a cashier who has a guard. What is the smallest number of guards needed?

It seems there are 3 guards needed. They should be posted at (a,i,g) as far as I can tell.  Anybody have a better idea?

Comment: Have you learned about this, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover? Your solution seems to be a minimum vertex cover, i.e. you have the correct solution. This graph cannot be covered by two vertices, you can check every pair to verify this.

Comment: The maximum degree at any vertex is $3$, so any one guard watches at most $4$ cashiers. Thus, two guards aren't enough to watch $11$ cashiers. Your $3$-guard solution is therefore optimal ... but not unique: for instance, $(c, d, j)$ also works.

Comment: @Blue You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer ...

The maximum degree at any vertex is $3$, so any one guard watches at most $4$ cashiers. Thus, two guards aren't enough to watch $11$ cashiers. Your $3$-guard solution is therefore optimal ... but not unique: for instance, $(c, d, j)$ also works.